# Disable table recreation in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to build a simple web application using Spring Boot. When I restart the application all database tables are recreated. I tried setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `update` or `validate` but that doesn't help.

This is my configuration:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableHypermediaSupport
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        datasource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase");
        datasource.setUsername("myusername");
        datasource.setPassword("mypassword");
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("my.domain.package");
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        lef.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

Using --debug I get this (somewhat filtered):

```
2014-02-23 18:17:30.735  INFO 27716 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@66e43eb8: startup date [Sun Feb 23 18:17:30 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-02-23 18:17:31.354  INFO 27716 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'pageableResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration; factoryMethodName=pageableResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration; factoryMethodName=pageableResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration.class]]
2014-02-23 18:17:31.355  INFO 27716 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'sortResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration; factoryMethodName=sortResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration; factoryMethodName=sortResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration.class]]
2014-02-23 18:17:31.726  INFO 27716 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'viewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=thymeleafConfig; factoryMethodName=viewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [be/**************/******/ThymeleafConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=viewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2014-02-23 18:17:32.159  INFO 27716 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=applicationConfig; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class **.**************.******.ApplicationConfig] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]]
2014-02-23 18:17:32.160  INFO 27716 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'entityManagerFactory': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=applicationConfig; factoryMethodName=entityManagerFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class **.**************.******.ApplicationConfig] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=entityManagerFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]]
2014-02-23 18:17:32.160  INFO 27716 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'jpaVendorAdapter': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=applicationConfig; factoryMethodName=jpaVendorAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class **.**************.******.ApplicationConfig] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jpaVendorAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]]
2014-02-23 18:17:33.031  INFO 27716 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9ca466b9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2014-02-23 18:17:33.074  INFO 27716 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2014-02-23 18:17:33.092  INFO 27716 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2014-02-23 18:17:33.102  INFO 27716 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2014-02-23 18:17:33.779  INFO 27716 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2014-02-23 18:17:33.779  INFO 27716 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
2014-02-23 18:17:33.909  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-02-23 18:17:33.909  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3177 ms
2014-02-23 18:17:35.028  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-02-23 18:17:35.028  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2014-02-23 18:17:35.124  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-02-23 18:17:35.385  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
2014-02-23 18:17:35.457  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2014-02-23 18:17:35.592  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
2014-02-23 18:17:35.622  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.1.Final}
2014-02-23 18:17:35.627  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate}
2014-02-23 18:17:35.628  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2014-02-23 18:17:35.655  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration      : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2014-02-23 18:17:35.899  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.s.j.c.i.ConnectionProviderInitiator  : HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
2014-02-23 18:17:36.256  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
2014-02-23 18:17:36.268  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2014-02-23 18:17:36.284  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
2014-02-23 18:17:36.292  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2014-02-23 18:17:36.481  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table project drop constraint FK_4725849e7c4543e3885bbd3a3a9
2014-02-23 18:17:36.488 ERROR 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table project drop constraint FK_4725849e7c4543e3885bbd3a3a9
2014-02-23 18:17:36.488 ERROR 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: constraint "fk_4725849e7c4543e3885bbd3a3a9" of relation "project" does not exist
Hibernate: alter table project drop constraint FK_56d354acd26e412daa99d5584ff
2014-02-23 18:17:36.489 ERROR 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table project drop constraint FK_56d354acd26e412daa99d5584ff
2014-02-23 18:17:36.489 ERROR 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: constraint "fk_56d354acd26e412daa99d5584ff" of relation "project" does not exist
Hibernate: drop table if exists company cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists project cascade
Hibernate: create table company (id  serial not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table project (id  serial not null, reference varchar(255), company int4, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table project add constraint FK_4725849e7c4543e3885bbd3a3a9 foreign key (company) references company
2014-02-23 18:17:36.577  INFO 27716 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Comment: It's probably this line: `hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);`

Comment: `hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false)` doesn't help either.

Comment: Can you ru nyour app with "--debug" (on command line) or `-Ddebug` (system property) and attach the autoconfiguration report (or any bits of it that mention Hibernate or JPA)? I think you are controlling the JPA configuration completely there, but it would be good just to check.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your configuration isn't a `@Configuration` class.

Next to that I suggest that you use the power of Spring Boot. Which means I would suggest removing everything but the `DataSource` configuration and simply add an application.properties file with the following properties

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

This should give you the desired behavior, with less coding.

You could even remove the datasource if you have either commons-dbcp or tomcat-pool in your classpath and adding the following properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

Answer (score 19):

If you are using spring boot, you could do it by configuration over the config file. Hibernate has all this possibilities:

1. validate (validate the schema)
2. update (update the schema if are changes)
3. create (create the schema)
4. create-drop (create the schema and drop it at the end)

but if you want don't do anything, spring boot add other chance, use as follow:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ApplicationConfig` is not `@Configuration`. I imagine that means the Spring Boot autoconfig will also be applied. Can you try adding that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a in-memory database then every time you start/stop spring boot application - it will recreate the whole thing unless you mention/configure spring boot to use the database from file system.

update your @Configuration or application.properties for below property

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/Users/user_name/database_file_name
```

Also check, you should not have spring.datasource.initialization-mode in config.